# custom AUTO INCREMENT value not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following sql code to create a table

```
CREATE TABLE db.object (
  `objid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `object_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`objid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

However, the values in the objid are coming out as 1,2,3... (The insert statement is not adding the ids)

Shouldn't `AUTO_INCREMENT=2` make the objid start from 2 instead of 1

Comment: You could do `AUTO_INCREMENT(1,2)` as well, which will start `objid` from 1 and increment the value 2.

Comment: @whatthefish yes, however I want to know if the above query is incorrect and resulting in this erroneous behavior

Comment: Can you show your insert statement?

Comment: If you care about the value of the incrementing id, then that can point to a more fundamental flaw in your schema design.

Answer (score 2):

With InnoDB tables, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value will be *reset* to the maximum value (plus 1) when the table is opened. The auto increment value exists only in memory, it is not persisted on disk.

A table open would happen, for example, when the MySQL instance was shutdown and  then restarted, and a reference is made to the table.

A table can also be closed at other times. For example, when `open_table_cache` is exceeded (that is, when a large number of other tables is opened), MySQL will close some of the open tables, to make room in the cache for newly opened tables.

I believe this behavior is documented somewhere in the MySQL Reference Manual.

Comment: It is documented, as alluded in my answer. :) +1, didn't know exceeding table cache would also trigger this behavior. Too many exceptions...

Comment: @bishop: i didn't see your answer until after I posted mine. A server restart will reset InnoDB auto_increment for sure. As your answer (rightly) points out, it's not just a server restart that resets AUTO_INCREMENT. I think it's the "table open" that does the reset, and closing and opening tables is something that InnoDB does automatically "behind the scenes".

Answer (score 1):

I used your SQL, created the object table and entered two values for `object_type` and `objid` started at 2.  Can't see anything wrong here...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might. There are enough exceptions and gotchas with auto-inc on InnoDB tables that it bears urging a [full review of the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html).

That said, there is one scenario I can think of where MySQL ignores the initializer value. I'll quote the documentation:

> InnoDB uses the in-memory auto-increment counter as long as the server runs. When the server is stopped and restarted, InnoDB reinitializes the counter for each table for the first INSERT to the table, as described [here]:
>
> > InnoDB executes the equivalent of the following statement on the first insert into a table containing an AUTO_INCREMENT column after a restart:
> >
> > `SELECT MAX(ai_col) FROM table_name FOR UPDATE;`
>
> A server restart also cancels the effect of the AUTO_INCREMENT = N table option in CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements, which you can use with InnoDB tables to set the initial counter value or alter the current counter value.

So if you create that table, then do a server restart (like as part of a deployment process), you'll get a nice value of `1` for the initial row. If you want to countermand this, you need to create the table, *then insert a dummy row with the auto-inc value you want*, then restart, *then delete the dummy row*.